# Failed to instantiate [..]: No default constructor found;

Tags: spring

I'm getting:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mz.server.rest.braintree.webhooks.SubscriptionWebhook]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.mz.server.rest.braintree.webhooks.SubscriptionWebhook.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1098)
    ... 22 more
```

Even though I have defined this constructor in my `applicatioContext-restapi.xml` file:

```xml
<bean id="subscriptionWebhook" class="com.mz.server.rest.braintree.webhooks.SubscriptionWebhook">
    <constructor-arg ref="dslContext" />
</bean>
```

Any idea why?

```java
@RestController
public class SubscriptionWebhook {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(SubscriptionWebhook.class.getName());

    private AdminService adminService;      

    public SubscriptionWebhook(DSLContext ctx) {
        this.adminService = new AdminService(ctx);
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is for `com.mz.server.rest.UserVerificationResource`, not `com.mz.server.rest.braintree.webhooks.SubscriptionWebhook`

Comment: @mszymborski Thanks for the hint and sorry for the confusion. This was a copy & paste error. I have more than one object which I try to use like this. I corrected my post ..

Comment: have you tried to simply inject it using annotations in the controller? @Inject/@Autowired

Comment: @mszymborski I'm not too familiar with Spring yet - I think I didn't get it how the autowiring/injection works with Spring. I will take a look at it :)

Comment: the direct equivalent of your xml would be @Qualifier("dslContext") applied to the constructor.

Comment: @mszymborski I just tried this and it seems to work - but the reason why I want this to happen via constructor is because I need to pass the `DSLContext` object down to another layer. Doing this in the constructor appears to me as the simplest way. If I use `@Autowired` then I'd need to do this initialization somewhere else.

Comment: You can also apply this annotation to the constructor, it's going to work just as your xml equivalent.

Comment: @mszymborski Hm, the compiler says otherwise: "*The annotation \@Qualifier is disallowed for this location*".

Comment: Sorry, I meant it being applied to the constructor's parameter - `public Whatever(@Qualifier("asfasd") String foo)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Spring 3(ish) you can configure your container by applying `@Component` annotations to classes. `@Controller` annotation is defined as follows:

```
@Target(value=TYPE)
@Retention(value=RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Component
public @interface Controller
```

Which means classes annotated by it are going to get picked up, too. And `RestController` is just `Controller` and `ResponseBody` put together.

Anyway as you admitted in the comments you have enabled component scanning, and the configuration in `xml` is not going to get picked up in this case.

What you could do is convert the xml configuration to annotation-based injection, like that:

```
@RestController
public class SubscriptionWebhook {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(SubscriptionWebhook.class.getName());

    private AdminService adminService;      

    public SubscriptionWebhook(@Qualifier("dslContext") DSLContext ctx) {
        this.adminService = new AdminService(ctx);
    }
}
```

`Qualifier` annotation is going to look in the container for a bean with name/id `dslContext` and inject it in the constructor. Alternatively you can use the `javax.inject` `Named` annotation, or if this is the only bean with that type, Spring's `@Autowired` or JSR-330's `@Inject`.

Comment: That's neat! Thank you for helping me out! :)

Answer (score 0):

Annotation @RestController is autodetected by spring. Spring will create a bean for you so you shouldn't add bean definition in the xml, because it would create a second bean. If you want to inject another bean into the controller just use @Autowired. So the solution in your case is:

1. Remove "subscriptionWebhook" bean definition from the xml
2. Add @Autowired on SubscriptionWebhook constructor